# Trouble passing array to SwiftMailer from Php/MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, swiftmailer

Hung up on getting Swift “setTo” to accept an array from MySQL query.  The code below only sends to the LAST person in the result set / list.  Have read at least a dozen related threads on stack and the docs from Swift but they seem to only show how to hard code values OR make a lot of assumptions.  Hoping for a more complete example that might also help others who aren't 100% on Php arrays and passing to Swift.

```
[...php connection code...]
// query email addresses
$sql = 'select emailaddress from customerlist;';
$result = mysql_query($sql );
if($result === FALSE) { 
    die(mysql_error()); // ToDo: better error handling 
} 

// create array from results
$cDistribArray = array();
while($rowEmail = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $cDistribArray = $rowEmail['emailaddress'];
}

[edit: issue was code above, CORRECTED below, thanks Sven]
// create array from results
$cDistribArray = array();
while($rowEmail = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $cDistribArray[] = $rowEmail['emailaddress'];
}


[...skip to Swift message create code...]

$message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Subject')
    ->setFrom(array('sender@yourserver.com' => 'Sender Name'))
    ->setTo($cDistribArray)
    ->setBody($cEmailBody,'text/html');
```

I'm sure it's something obvious I'm doing wrong with the array but after reading many articles on how to create arrays and Swift and an inbox full of test messages that only have more than one address when I hard code...stuck! Would appreciate any assistance offered.

Comment: Apart from stating the obvious about `mysql_*` functions being deprecated, you miss a trailing `'` after `emailaddress`.

Comment: corrected in the mock-up but that wasn't the issue, the result set comes back fine as I can echo the individual results and they all show.  Issue seems to be either 1.) getting Swift to "see" all rows in the array, or, somehow I'm not passing all the rows to the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This overwrites every previous result with the current fetched mail address:

```
$cDistribArray = $rowEmail['emailaddress'];
```

You probably want something like this:

```
$cDistribArray[] = $rowEmail['emailaddress']; // Add new mail address to the array
```

Comment: I knew it was something bonehead I was missing - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The code that's sending the email is outside of the while loop. It'll only ever send an email to the last record. Have you tried this?

```
// create array from results
$cDistribArray = array();
while($rowEmail = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $cDistribArray = $rowEmail['emailaddress'];

    [...skip to Swift message create code...]

    $message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Subject')
        ->setFrom(array('sender@yourserver.com' => 'Sender Name'))
        ->setTo($cDistribArray)
        ->setBody($cEmailBody,'text/html');

}
```

Comment: hello and thanks for the reply.  According to my reading of the Swift docs, setTo can't be used in a loop, there's another set you can use for bulk if you don't want anyone to see the others email but thats not an issue.  I can try this but it appeear to be creating multiple instances of the message object as its within the loop.

Comment: Confirmed, I tried this approach with no change in the outcome (ie the result set has multiple row but the email only is sent to the contents of the last row).  Thanks for trying!

Comment: Ach, fair enough - I didn't realise that about SM, thought you just had a basic control flow error!